# craft CMS broken after reverting nystudio107/craft-seomatic from 3.4.24 to 3.3.48

Tags: craftcms

We upgraded nystudio107/craft-seomatic (from 3.3.48 to 3.4.24) and a bunch of other packages, but then found our upgrade did not work and so we had to revert. However, now we get an error whenever we open our site after this downgrade:

Setting unknown property: nystudio107\seomatic\models\MetaGlobalVars::inherited

Our downgrade back to the previous version was as follows:

```
Downgrading nystudio107/craft-seomatic (3.4.24 => 3.3.48): Extracting archive
```

I am not sure where this comes from but I suspect a database change is causing this.  How can we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a full backup of the website with the database before the upgrade?
If you have the backup try restoring it to the old one with the database the package changes made changes in the database. In case you don't have a backup try removing these packages from the project you can use `composer remove nystudio107/craft-seomatic` Hope this helps you with the same.